# Erro ao executar uma trigger ORA-04092: não é possível em um gatilho

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g, job

Estou com o seguinte problema: 
*- Não estou conseguindo executar um job (Scheduling) depois de um insert resgatado pela trigger.*

> Linha 2: ORA-04092: não é possível  em um gatilho ORA-06512: em
>   "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 135 ORA-06512: em "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line
>   271 ORA-06512: em "TRG_GET_LAST_INSERT", line 9

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_get_last_insert
BEFORE INSERT
  ON TB_TOKEN
  FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
vToken NUMBER;

BEGIN

   SELECT ID INTO vToken FROM TB_TOKEN WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TB_TOKEN );
   IF vToken IS NOT NULL THEN

        dbms_scheduler.create_job ( 
            job_name => 'TESTE_JOB', 
            job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
            job_action => 'BEGIN 
                               DELETE FROM TB_TOKEN WHERE ID = ' + vToken + '
                            END;COMMIT;', 
            enabled => true, 
            start_date    => sysdate + 1/24,
            repeat_interval=> null
        ); 



   END IF;

END;
```

*Alguém sabe a melhor forma de executar isso?
A ideia é passar o parâmetro que é resgatado e deletar ele depois de **1 hora**.*

Comment: tenta fazer declarar vToken  da seguinte forma:

`vToken  TB_TOKEN.ID%type;`

Comment: @LucasBrogni em qual parte do código no DECLARE ?

Comment: Onde está `vToken NUMBER;` na parte do declare.

Comment: Então @LucasBrogni o erro agora é de conversão `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: erro: character to number conversion error numérico ou de valor`

Comment: Grave a datahora da operação , rode o job de x em x minutos e delete os registros com mais de 60 minutos , creio ser mais simples.